# Java - Constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, Java does not insert one either

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor, superclass

First, this is what I read on [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com)

*Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.*

But when I test my code, the no argument constructor of `class B` **does not have a superclass constructor AND Java doesn't add one.** Why is this? This is what I had expected:

```
   public B(){
        super(); //<--- Why didn't Java add this superclass constructor? 
        this(false);
        System.out.println("b1");
    }
```

Does it has something to do with the fact that the "public B()" constructor calls another constructor which calls another one which DOES have a superclass constructor?

The output I get is: a2
a1
b2
b3
b1
c1
a2
a1
b2
b3
b1
c1
c2

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new C();
        new C(1.0);
    }
}
```

Class A

```
public class A {
    public A(){
        this(5);
        System.out.println("a1");
    }

    public A(int x){
        System.out.println("a2");
    }
}
```

Class B

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(){
        this(false);
        System.out.println("b1");
    }

    public B(int x){
        super();
        System.out.println("b2");
    }

    public B(boolean b){
        this(2);
        System.out.println("b3");
    }
}
```

Class C

```
public class C extends B {
    public C(){
        System.out.println("c1");
    }

    public C(double x){
        this();
        System.out.println("c2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of the output were you not expecting?

Comment: I had expected it to start of with [a2 a1 a2 a1 a2 a1..] because of I thougt the compiler would add super() in the first and third constructor of class B. What @Mureinik says makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `this(args)` is evaluated before anything else. So `B()` calls `B(boolean)`, which calls `B(int)`, which explicitly calls `super()`.

Comment: +1 And if it didn't work this way, super() would be invoked twice.