# Questioning the order in which the code is executed

Tags: java, sequence, extends, extend

So I stumbled across this piece of code ([Java - Constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, Java does not insert one either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340310/java-constructor-does-not-explicitly-invoke-a-superclass-constructor-java-doe))...

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new C();
        new C(1.0);
    }
}

class A {
    public A(){
        this(5);
        System.out.println("a1");
    }

    public A(int x){
        System.out.println("a2");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B(){
        this(false);
        System.out.println("b1");
    }

    public B(int x){
        super();
        System.out.println("b2");
    }

    public B(boolean b){
        this(2);
        System.out.println("b3");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public C(){
        System.out.println("c1");
    }

    public C(double x){
        this();
        System.out.println("c2");
    }
}
```

And the output that I got is a2 a1 b2 b3 b1 c1 a2 a1 b2 b3 b1 c1 c2

I was expecting it to be c1 c2 only but I just cannot wrap my head around the sequence in which the code is executed.

I would love a detailed explanation, just to make sure I understand things clearly enough. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: if a constructor doesn't explicitly delegate to another through `this(...)` or `super(...)`, it's equivalent to having `super()`. So imagine the parameterless constructor for `C` starts `super();` - would that clear up your confusion?

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot that super() is invoked even if not explicitly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting classes call `super()` implicitely at the beginning of the constructor.

Thus, the execution is as follows:

`C()` --> `B()` --> `A()` --> `A(5)` --> `print('a2')` --> `print('a1')` --> `B(false)` --> `B(2)` --> `print('b2')` --> `print('b3')` --> `print('b1')` --> `print('c1')` (this finishes the very first call to `C()`)

`C(1.0)` --> does the exact same trajectory for a2, a1, b2, b3, b1, c1, and then finally `print('c2')` to finish the function.